# CMS with bi-language support and Video

Tags: php, perl, content-management-system, mysql5

I have a project that needs to have support for Arabic (rtl), and french(ltr)

and video support, About the language i can't seem to find any CMS , multi-language ready

it is not problem that i can build it with a home-grown MVC, but about that video stuff,

i have no idea , any one can give me any links on how to let the client upload vids in admin ,

and display them in other side ? i really have no idea about the subject , and google lead me

to no-where

about the CMS : is there any thing that make it easy to have 2 languages ?(if not just ignore that , and focus on the video question)

EDIT : PHP-MYSQL is my main plans , and i have the right to use perl-cgi

Comment: Anything missing here ? Just tell me and i will try to provide more infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Looking at every signle possibilty i found something that was very usefull

www.opencart.com

Yes this is not a CMS but the way it handles the multilanguages problem is very inovative and should be

used where possible in every CMS, For me I used its MVCL system on a website that is not a

ShoppingCart but needs multi language support, If i had time i will release my based job as OpenSource

(I am busy currently and it needs to get stripped of the content)

About the Video stuff , it seems like i was overestimating the whole thing , it is only upload and

put it on a player,

Answer (score 2):

Uploading a file is a solved problem, I'm not giving any comment about that topic.

To display video in a Web page the modern way, read:

- the [video chapter in Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html)
- the [Modernizr documentation](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/)

I recommend [CatalystX::I18N](http://p3rl.org/CatalystX%3a%3aI18N) for writing an internationalised Web app, it makes it very easy to handle everything correctly.

Comment: i need support for IE (sorry didn't mention above)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the concrete5 CMS will work for you:
http://www.concrete5.org

Have a look at these links:

- http://www.concrete5.org/developers/translate/
- http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/installation/installing_c5_in_other_languages
- http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/generate-a-.mo-file-with-.po-file-from-mygengo-with-poedit-insta/

Comment: This answer makes me happy :)

Comment: @DavidStockton Yeah Dave! Good call.